# Converting Time Range into Readable format in R

Tags: r, time

I am having trouble converting a time range in a column to a readable data for R. How would I go about converting this?

[1] "05:30P -08:00P" "07:00A -09:35A" "08:00A -10:30A" "08:55P -11:00P" "06:00P -06:30P"

```
c("05:30P -08:00P", "07:00A -09:35A", "08:00A -10:30A", "08:55P -11:00P", 
"06:00P -06:30P")
```

Comment: What is the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to convert to `Datetime`, an option is to split at the  `-` into two columns and then use `as.POSIXct` to do the conversion

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
str_replace_all(str1, "([AP])", "\\1M") %>% 
    tibble(str1 = .) %>% 
    separate(str1, into = c('start', 'end'), sep="\\s*-") %>% 
    mutate(across(c(start, end), ~ as.POSIXct(., format = '%I:%M %p')))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  start               end                
#  <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1 2020-08-19 17:30:00 2020-08-19 20:00:00
#2 2020-08-19 07:00:00 2020-08-19 09:35:00
#3 2020-08-19 08:00:00 2020-08-19 10:30:00
#4 2020-08-19 20:55:00 2020-08-19 23:00:00
#5 2020-08-19 18:00:00 2020-08-19 18:30:00
```

---

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
str_replace_all(str1, "([AP])", "\\1M") %>% 
     tibble(str1 = .) %>% 
     separate(str1, into = c('start', 'end'), sep="\\s*-") %>% 
     mutate(across(c(start, end), ~ parse_date_time(., 'IMp')))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("05:30P -08:00P", "07:00A -09:35A", "08:00A -10:30A", "08:55P -11:00P", 
"06:00P -06:30P")
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R attempt using `strcapture` to separate the timestamps out to two parts:

```
dr <- c("05:30P -08:00P", "07:00A -09:35A", "08:00A -10:30A", "08:55P -11:00P", 
"06:00P -06:30P")

tms <- strcapture(r"((\d+:\d+[AP])[- ]+(\d+:\d+[AP]))", dr, proto=list(start="",end=""))
tms[] <- lapply(tms, function(x) as.POSIXct(paste0(x, "M"), format="%I:%M%p", tz="UTC"))

#                start                 end
#1 2020-08-20 17:30:00 2020-08-20 20:00:00
#2 2020-08-20 07:00:00 2020-08-20 09:35:00
#3 2020-08-20 08:00:00 2020-08-20 10:30:00
#4 2020-08-20 20:55:00 2020-08-20 23:00:00
#5 2020-08-20 18:00:00 2020-08-20 18:30:00
```

Comment: `strcapture` is instantly my next function to "master" ... thanks @thelatemail

Comment: @r2evans - it is under appreciated and really a quite neat interface for regex based splitting.